# Mock class used by class under test in Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I want to mock a dependency (imported class) of the class under test. One example:

`classToTest.ts`

```
import {MyRespository} from './myRepository'

export class ClassToTest {
    constructor() {
        this.myRepository = new MyRepository()
    }

    methodToTest() {
        ...
        this.myRepository.fetchSomeData()
        ...
    }
}
```

`myRepository.ts`

```
export class MyRepository {
    constructor() {}

    fetchSomeData() {
        ...
    }
}
```

How can I use jest to mock `MyRepository` without using dependency injection for `ClassToTest`?

Answer (score 1):

It would have been easier if you use [constructor injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-constructor-injection/) so you would just pass your mock object to `ClassToTest`.

```
import { MyRepository } from "./myRepository";

export class ClassToTest {
  constructor(private myRepository: MyRepository) {}

  methodToTest() {
    this.myRepository.fetchSomeData();
  }
}
```

And your test would be just:

```
import { ClassToTest } from "./main";
import { MyRepository } from "./myRepository";

describe("my test", () => {
  let obj: ClassToTest;
  let mockRepo = {
    fetchSomeData: jest.fn(),
  } as MyRepository;

  beforeEach(() => {
    obj = new ClassToTest(mockRepo);
  });

  it("should test my method", () => {
    obj.methodToTest();
    expect(mockRepo.fetchSomeData).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

---

Or if you want to continue with your approach, you can mock your class implementation (see [this approach](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#replacing-the-mock-using-mockimplementation-or-mockimplementationonce) for example):

```
import { ClassToTest } from "./main";

const fetchSomeDataMock = jest.fn();

jest.mock("./myRepository", () => {
  return {
    MyRepository: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        fetchSomeData: fetchSomeDataMock,
      };
    }),
  };
});

describe("my test", () => {
  let obj: ClassToTest;

  beforeEach(() => {
    obj = new ClassToTest();
  });

  it("should test my method", () => {
    obj.methodToTest();
    expect(fetchSomeDataMock).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

See more:

- https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks

Comment: Thanks! The second approach seems really nice! However, one thing that isn't clear to me is what path you should provide to `jest.mock(path, ...)` should it be the relative path from the test file to `myRepository.ts` or the relative path between `classToTest.ts` and `myRepository.ts`?

Comment: The path should be the relative path from the test to `myRepository.ts`